# How to know which user run build in Jenkinsfile

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to get the name of the user that's running a build in Jenkinsfile:

```
...
user = User.current().getFullName()
...
```

but get "SYSTEM".
How get correct username?

Jenkins 1.651.3

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found solution:

```
def build = currentBuild.rawBuild
def cause = build.getCause(hudson.model.Cause.UserIdCause.class)
def name = cause.getUserName()
echo "User: " + name
```

print name of user which run build.

Answer (score 5):

If you encounter "Scripts not allowed" this also works;

[Install the Build User Vars plugin found here](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Build+User+Vars+Plugin)

... then wrap your step, something like this:

```
steps {
    script {
        wrap([$class: 'BuildUser']) {

            var name = "${BUILD_USER}"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't start by comparing your solution to some other one. Just explain why it doesn't trigger "Scripts not allowed", and why it is relevant here. ;)

Comment: This can also be wrapped in a function and called like: def buildUserId() {
    wrap([$class: 'BuildUser']) {
        return "${BUILD_USER_ID}"
    }
}